# Graph 3-colors coloring with the use of the given function

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, graph-coloring

I have the function three_colorability(n,E) which gives output true(when the graph with those edges and vertices can be coloured with 3 colors) or false(if not). (!there is no parameter to know what has been coloured already)
We assume that this function works in linear time complexity.

I have to make 3-coloring algorithm of the given undirected graph G with the use of the given function which will work in polynomial time.

I can't come to the solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 3 new nodes, named `C1`, `C2` and `C3` by colour they represent. Add edges between new nodes `(C1,C2)`, `(C2,C3)` and `(C1,C3)`. If `three_colorability(V,E)` is true than `three_colorability(V+{C1,C2,C3},E+{(C1,C2),(C2,C3),(C1,C3)})` is also true.

For each (original) vertex `v`, `three_colorability()` returns true for at least one of graphs with added two edge of `{(v,C1), (v,C2), (v,C3)}`. E.g. if `three_colorability()` returns true for graph with added edges `{(v,C2), (v,C3)}`, it means that `v` can be coloured with colour 1.

To find colour for all vertices, incrementally find vertex colour and add these 2 edges in a graph.